# How to correct this for-loop code?

Tags: for-loop, python-2.7, performance

```
# Define the project name and path for input files
# need to use \ before \t and \ to print these characters
Project = "101"
path_Directory =  "C:\Users\\tp\Desktop\project\\"
full_path_Directory = path_Directory + Project

# Set path for files in the program
File_stock = full_path_Directory + "_stock.txt"
File_exchange = full_path_Directory + "_exchange.txt"
File_country = full_path_Directory + "_country.txt"

var_set = [File_stock, File_exchange, File_country]

  for var in var_set:
    var = open(var,'r')
    var = var.read()[3:]
    print var
```

I created a var_set to contain the 3 variables - File_stock, File_exchange and File_country because I thought it would be more efficient to loop through the repetitive tasks. While the output from the code shown above is correct, but when i typed: "print stock" or "print exchange" or print "country", the output is always wrong because it shows the path directory instead of the data from the text files.

Does anyone know what could be the reason and how should I fix it?

Comment: Your code does not contain any definitions for `stock`, `exchange` or `country`. Your variable names do not match currently.

Comment: Tip: use raw string literals to avoid ``\`` being interpreted as an escape code: `r'C:\Users\tp\Desktop\project'`. You cannot use a slash as the last character then though. `os.path.join()` is great for generating longer paths. `os.path.join(path_Directory, Project)`.

Comment: Martijn, I am sorry. stock should be File_stock, exchange should be File_exchange and country should be File_country. Ok, I will import os and set the path by writing path_Directory = os.path.join(path_Directory, Project). Thanks again!

Comment: Again, you can [edit] your question to correct mistakes.

Comment: Noted with thanks. I am going to start on a good foundation by getting a book on Python. Any suggestion guys?

Comment: The http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ is great, and there is a whole list at http://wiki.python.org/moin/FrontPage#start to get you going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store per-file data in a data structure, you'll need to use a `dict` or similar to do so:

```
Project = "101"

path_Directory =  r"C:\Users\tp\Desktop\project"
names = ['stock', 'exchange', 'country']
data = {}

for name in names:
    path = os.path.join(path_Directory, '{0}_{1}.txt'.format(Project, name))
    data[name] = open(path, 'r').read(3)
```

I also replaced your `.read()[:3]` with `.read(3)` to just read three characters instead of reading the whole file; it's more efficient.

Now `data` will have three keys, each pointing to the 3 characters read from each file:

```
print data['stock']  # prints 'xyz'. etc.
```

Comment: Martijn, I was trying to get rid of the first 3 characters in each file. I suspect it is due to some encoding problem. It appears in each of the text file. By the way, what does the {0}_{1} represent?

Comment: Got it! 0 represents the project name and 1 represents the name of the variable. Very elegant!

Comment: Ah, indeed, not the first 3 but everything *but* the first three. :-) Yes, the string formatting syntax used can be found here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

Comment: @TingPing: I suspect the first 3 bytes are the [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8); check with [`codecs.BOM_UTF8`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.BOM_UTF8). If so, do `.read().decode('utf_8_sig']` to get unicode data.